# Where can I find the centos firewall log file?

Tags: logging, centos, firewall

I have some ports block by firewall when i set my centos server, such as gerrit can't send email by timeout error when I stop firewalld service, it works. And same as shadowsocks, when I start firewalld service, I can't get anything by my server. I have already opened server port 8388 & 8389 & 465 & 25, but it just didn't work.

I want to cat some firewall log file to find which port wouldn't be aborted. And I cat the file /usr/sbin/firewalld author is you, and firewall import config,config set the log file location. So, how to locate the log file's location?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off-topic here (but ontopic on the https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 10):

**Log files**

Logs are in `/var/log/firewalld`.

You can use `tail` to autrenew the output and display the last few lines:

```
tail -f /var/log/firewalld
```

You may need to activate logging on startup with `--debug`.
You can just add it in `/etc/sysconfig/firewalld`:

```
FIREWALLD_ARGS=--debug=10
```

and restart the process with `sudo systemctl restart firewalld`

**Add the service to firewalld**

Also you might need to add the service itself like so (replace the `https`):

```
firewall-cmd --set-default-zone=dmz 2>&1 > /dev/null
firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --permanent --add-service=https 2>&1 > /dev/null
firewall-cmd --reload 2>&1 > /dev/null
```